# Preprocessing input text before calling ElasticSearch API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have a Java client that allows indexing documents on a local ElasticSearch server.
I now want to build a simple Web UI that allows users to query the ES index by typing in some text in a form.

My problem is that, before calling ES APIs to issue the query, I want to preprocess the user input by calling some Java code.

What is the easiest and "cleanest" way to achieve this?

- Should I create my own APIs so that the UI can access my Java code?
- Should I build the UI with JSP so that I can directly call my Java
  code?
- Can I somehow make ElasticSearch execute my Java code before
  the query is executed? (Perhaps by creating my own ElasticSearch plugin?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I opted for the simple solution of using Json-based RESTful APIs. Time proved this to be quite flexible and effective for my case, so I thought I should share it:

1. My Java code exposes its ability to query an ElasticSearch index, by running an HTTP server and responding to client requests with Json-formatted ES results. I created the HTTP server with a few lines of code, by using [sun.net.HttpServer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html). There are more serious/complex HTTP servers out there (such as [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/)), but this was very quick to adopt and required zero configuration headaches.
2. My Web UI makes HTTP GET requests to the Java server, receives Json-formatted data and consumes it happily. My UI is implemented in PHP, but any web language does the job, as long as you can issue HTTP requests.

This solution works really well in my case, because it allows to have no dependencies on ES plugins. I can do any sort of *pre-processing* before calling ES, and even *post-process* ES output before sending the results back to the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of pre-processing, you can create an Elasticsearch plugin as custom analyser or custom filter: you essentially extend the appropriate Lucene class(es) and wrap everything into an Elasticsearch plugin. Once the plugin is loaded, you can configure the custom analyser and apply it to the related fields. There are a lot of analysers and filters already available in Elasticsearch, so you might want to have a look at those before writing your own.

Elasticsearch plugins: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/modules-plugins.html (a list of known plugins at the end)

Defining custom analysers: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-analyzers.html

Comment: Thanks for your help. In the end I opted for simple RESTful APIs http://stackoverflow.com/a/35923855/2091700